# Does scaling required for this kind of datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I have a dataset with features like views of a product (in hundreds of thousands), clicks on the products (in thousands), conversion rate (in decimal such as 7.6%) and sales (in hundreds). Do I need to do a scaling of the data for clustering?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on the data and the method you use. For instance, many clustering algorithms (e.g., K-Means) use a distance metric (Euclidean distance, Manhattan distance, etc.), so it's recommended to scale data.

You may find handy :
[Do Clustering algorithms need feature scaling in the pre-processing stage?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22795/do-clustering-algorithms-need-feature-scaling-in-the-pre-processing-stage)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21222/are-mean-normalization-and-feature-scaling-needed-for-k-means-clustering